# Option in SQL Server Management Studio to expand columns in results grid for large text display

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a column that contains a bunch of text.  Currently the only way I can view it is in the standard tiny cell.

Is there a way to automatically expand this cell to the size of the text?

Is it possible to do this in the 'edit' mode as well?

Comment: If you open up the table on edit mode, you should be able to adjust the cell size but may not be to the length of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with SQL or T-SQL, per se. This is a function of whatever user interface you are using to display your query results. I assume in this case you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). I don't believe there is a way to automatically expand columns to fit the largest value width. You might want to try SQL Server Development Tools (SSDT). Although I don't think this does it either. Another option might be to send your results to a text file (which is an option) and then viewing the file in an editor.

You could always write your own user interface that does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSMS and you have grid I don't think you can resize the columns. you can check this [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2346/different-options-for-query-results-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

If you press Ctrl+T this will change the grid mode into text mode where you can see results in text format with the complete values of all columns.